# Image Upload and Management system PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

Good morning, I have an issue with image uploading on a blog/cms I'm creating. Their is a post article page where user can upload a picture and then write his article. Basically, what I want to do is upload an image into uploads/ foler and then verify if it exists. If file does not exists, it will be uploaded and a reference will be inserted into the database Posts table after post is created and if it exists it wont be uploaded but a reference will still be inserted into the Posts table. The image insert function verifies picture size, but it also generates a new name for file afterwards in sha1 format. So here is the function that inserts the image:

```
   function addImage() {

    try {

        // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
        // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
        if (
                !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
                is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
        ) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
        }

        // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
        switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
        }

        // You should also check filesize here. 
        if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 1000000) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        }


        // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
        // Check MIME Type by yourself.
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        if (false === $ext = array_search(
                $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']), array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
                ), true
                )) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
        }

        // You should name it uniquely.
        // DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
        // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
        if (!move_uploaded_file(
                        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'], sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s', $sha2 = sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']), $ext
                        )
                )) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
        }


function addImage() {

    try {

        // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
        // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
        if (
                !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
                is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
        ) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
        }

        // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
        switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
        }

        // You should also check filesize here. 
        if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 1000000) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        }


        // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
        // Check MIME Type by yourself.
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        if (false === $ext = array_search(
                $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']), array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
                ), true
                )) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
        }
               if (file_exists($_SESSION['filefullname'])) {
                    echo "The file $filename exists";
                    $_SESSION['sha'] == "exists";
                       echo $_SESSION['sha'];
                    echo $_SESSION['filefullename'];
                } else {
                    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
                    $_SESSION['sha'] == "notexists";
                    $_SESSION['filefullname'] = $filename;
                    echo $_SESSION['sha'];
                    echo $_SESSION['filefullename'];
                }

        // You should name it uniquely.
        // DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
        // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
        if (!move_uploaded_file(
                        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'], sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s', $sha2 = sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']), $ext
                        )
                )) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
        }


        echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $path = 'C:/wamp64/www/blog_management/uploads/' . $sha2 . ".jpg";
}
        echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $path = 'C:/wamp64/www/blog_management/uploads/' . $sha2 . ".jpg";
}
```

So I'm wondering what would be the best way to proceed. Or is there a better easier way to do this? How are image uploads and management system usually created?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you are after! Best way to proceed where? What does an easier way mean to you?

Comment: I don't necessarily mean easier but the best way to implement a upload image system. The issue I have with the function to upload image above is that it if I try to use if file_exists, it always returns file exists. So where in the function should I put it to make sure if verifies properly? Or should I use another php function to do that?

Comment: Where inside the code did you use `file_exists` - also, what variable did you pass as an input?

Comment: As a bit of advice: do not ask such broad and opinionated questions, such as what's the best way to do sg because these questions are off-topic on SO and get closed very quickly. Simply copy-paste the code with the file_exists() code in it into the question and repeat the your previous comment as the question. This way you asked us a specific question that can be answered.

Comment: Thanks I just added the if exists code.